# Imprimindo itens de um array associativo de forma randômica

Tags: php, array

Estou criando um carrossel, onde terá 3 *sliders* contendo 15 imagens dentro de cada um, totalizando 45 imagens.

[image: matriz]

Eu criei um *array* associativo para exibir essas imagens de forma randômica, até aí tudo bem, no entanto, agora eu preciso que os 15 primeiros itens sejam fixo, onde eu consiga escolher quais os índices sejam exibidos primeiros e os outros 30 sejam exibidos de forma randômica mas sem repetir esses 15 que eu escolhi.

```
$clientes = array(
array(
    "nome" => "Cliente 1",
    "categoria" => "Turismo",
    "logo" => "turismo.jpg"
),
array(
    "nome" => "Suporte",
    "categoria" => "Tecnologia",
    "logo" => "suporte.jpg"
),
array(
    "nome" => "Faculdade Futura",
    "categoria" => "Educação",
    "logo" => "faculdade-futura.jpg"
),

shuffle($clientes);
foreach (array_slice($clientes, 0, 45) as $atributo => $valor):
   echo "{$valor["nome"]}";
endforeach;
);
```

Esse meu *array* tem mais de 60 itens, onde é exibido em outra parte do site, mas no carrossel só preciso de 45, por isso usei o `array_slice()`.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem imagino que isto funcione:

```
$tmp = $clientes;
shuffle(array_slice(tmp, 15, 30));
$novo = array_merge(array_slice($clientes, 0, 15), $tmp);
foreach ($novo as $atributo => $valor):
   echo "{$valor["nome"]}\n";
endforeach;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/POBNBt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zptlkyid-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ForEachIndex.php).

Eu embaralhei só do décimo sexto item pegando 30 (posso não ter entendido essa parte, pode ser que precise de todos os elementos menos 15, se for isso eu posso mudar a resposta) itens e concatenei com os 15 iniciais que não forma embaralhado.

Talvez seja isto (eu mudo se o AP clarificar):

```
$tmp = $clientes;
shuffle(array_slice(tmp, 15, count($clientes) - 15));
$novo = array_merge(array_slice($clientes, 0, 15), array_slice($tmp, 0, 30));
foreach ($novo as $atributo => $valor):
   echo "{$valor["nome"]}\n";
endforeach;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WRwrGJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/axzrvadc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ForEachIndex2.php).

Comment: Me desculpe se eu acabei causando uma confusão rs
Na verdade os 15 primeiros que vão ser fixos eu vou escolher, agora como irei escolher é que eu não sei, penso que a forma mais fácil seja pelo índice, ou então criar um atributo.